# GUI for localization in cakephp

Tags: cakephp, localization, internationalization

I have generated .pot file for my website and it works well. Now can i provide a GUI facility to give the translation option and modify the content of the .pot file ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

See http://www.poedit.net/ is the best choice - IMO.

Comment: My question itself is misleading, sorry. I need GUI option in my application, is there any cakephp methods to manage this operation ?

Comment: No, CakePHP is a framework and no application for managing translations. You can try to google for a plugin. There was a mozilla project in the past that was open source that allowed web based editing of translations but I dont remember the name of it.